# Is it possible to develop the back-end of a native mobile app using the python powered framework Django?

Tags: android, python, ios, django

I want to develop a online mobile app. I am thinking about using native languages to develop the front-ends, so Java for Android and Objective-C for iOS. However, for the back-end, can I use something like Django?

I have used django for a while, but the tutorials are really lacking, so can anyone point me to something that will help me understand how to show data handled by Django models on a front-end developed by Java for an android device (that is, by using XML I suppose).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Of course you can. Mobile apps, like browsers, are just clients, or specifically you can think of them as specialized browsers that can give a more native look.

It really depends on what kind of mobile app you want to develop, but you said you want a native mobile app. This will mean your mobile app will consume a Web API of some sorts. There is a Django package called [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) that can help you with that.

Basically, in a native mobile app, you will use whatever HTTP client the SDK comes with to interface with the Web API. That HTTP Client sends a request to Web API, Web API (can be written in Java/Python/Ruby etc) then processes that request and returns a response. That response will then be handled by your native mobile app, either to display some info or messages or whatever you want it to do.

On a more personal note, I recommend you stay away from XML unless you absolutely need to. JSON is enough for a lot of cases, and it is much much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. I've done this for my first app and others then. The backend technology is totally up to you, so feel free to take whatever you like.

The connection between backend and your apps should (but don't have to be) be something JSON-based. Standard REST works fine, Websockets also but have some issues on iOS.